# Root locus vs routh hurwitz criteria?

Tags: stability, root-locus, routh

What is the difference between root locus and routh hurwitz criteria? As according to layman knowledge, both techniques are used somehow to determine

Comment: Root locus shows how the closed loop poles move across the s-plane as a parameter (typically gain) is swept from 0 to infinity. Based on the branches, you can graphically/mathematically determine stability. On the root locus you might see the pole's path cross the imaginary axis, at this gain the system will flip from stable to unstable. Or you might see the pole locations stay on the left half plane forever, that is: stable for all gains.

Comment: Routh hurwitz criteria is a quick mathematical way to determine what gains are allowed whilst achieving stability. It doesn't show you the path of the poles, but it does tell you about the stability of a system and it's relation to a gain factor. Handmade root locus typically employ routh hurwitz matrices to determine when the closed loop pole crosses the imaginary axis. 

So in essence, root locus: Big picture of pole movement, 
Routh hurwitz: What gains (if any) lead to instability.

Comment: If gain is kept variable then rough Hurwitz criterion tells us if the system is stable or not if we vary the gain from 0 to infinity. It also tells us the number of CL poles on RHS of the jw plane. But it does not tell us the location of CL poles if gain varies. Root locus tells us the location of CL poles and the damping nature of the system.